# Unable to open all solution projects on Visual Studio 2015 - (Load failed/Unavailable)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have received, from another development team, an MVC project created on Visual Studio 2015. After unzipping the file and opening the solution with VS 2015 Community, I get various warning messages about missing files and most importantly, projects. The project was developed using Team Foundation server for source control, and I get a warning message when opening it that the server cannot be contacted.

Tackling the problem as possibly missing file paths and the like, I have tried the following:

- Deleting .user and .suo files: The 2 projects in question do not have files like that included.
- Attempting to reload the projects. This has led to an error message saying that the respective .csproj files for each missing project cannot be found. After this the message next to the project name in parentheses has changed from (unavailable) to (load failed)
- Running VS as admin and repeating the above.
- Remove and try to add the projects again: I couldn't achieve that as there is no .csproj file in the project's folders. Going in the folders I can find .csproj files, but they are actually .csproj.vspscc files, with the following content in them (in both project's cases):

  ```
  ""{
  "FILE_VERSION" = "9237"
  "ENLISTMENT_CHOICE" = "NEVER"
  "PROJECT_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" = ""
  "NUMBER_OF_EXCLUDED_FILES" = "0"
  "ORIGINAL_PROJECT_FILE_PATH" = ""
  "NUMBER_OF_NESTED_PROJECTS" = "0"
  "SOURCE_CONTROL_SETTINGS_PROVIDER" = "PROVIDER"
  }
  ```

My knowledge on source control and code-delivery-between-teams problems is limited. I have some concerns about this issue before seeing if it can actually be solved:

1. Is it possible that the code has actually been compromised *on purpose* by the other team? The fact that there are also missing .cs files might point to that.
2. Could it be that this is a common problem caused by lazily sharing code?

The people in question insist that there should be nothing wrong with the delivered code.

Comment: I can't answer your specific questions, but if the `.csproj` and `cs` files aren't there, there's no way for VS to load them without getting them from TFS.

Comment: Then, the way I see it, they must have had those files in their ignore list, right? So they tried to provide the code by copy-paste and thus question 2 is right.

Comment: Seeing as you have the SCC files, it sounds like they did a checkout then zipped that up and sent it to you: having a `.tfignore` file that excluded specific projects and code files in the solution wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe from what you are saying that there is no way for me to get access to those missing files without them sending them to me.

Comment: Unless they give you access to TFS, then I believe so.